How to turn off Google Search Network for app promotion on Adsense?
Does anyone know how to exclude Google Search Network and only show my ads on Display Network for app promotion on Adsense ?
I put 20 images but still %90 of the traffic on google play search.
I want this because, who comes from play store search has around %25 day 1 retention and who comes from display networks has %40 day 1 retention.
I could not find the option to turn it off or any options like how to play with network options.
